# Recover a cached file from .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, caching

I'm working in a simple cache system generated by php and responded from apache `.htaccess` (and in real server by nginx).

PHP creates the cache file into `public/cache/` with files like `public/cache/post/35/my-first-post.html`

VirtualHost is common to all projects, on develop we haven't a VirtualHost for each project:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www

    <Directory /var/www>
        Options -Indexes
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

`.htaccess` located in `/var/www/projects/current-project/public/.htaccess` should detect this cache file and return it.

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond cache/$1.html -f
    RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9/-]+)$ cache/$1.html [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Url is http://localhost/projects/current-project/public/post/35/my-first-post but production server is http://domain.com/post/35/my-first-post

And rewrite log:

```
[Sun May 08 13:55:11.236124 2016] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 3189] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 127.0.0.1:43494] 127.0.0.1 - - [localhost/sid#7f2d26745ae0][rid#7f2d2668e0a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/projects/current-project/public/] RewriteCond: input='cache/post/1/my-first-post.html' pattern='-f' => not-matched
```

File `perdir /var/www/projects/current-project/public/` + `input='cache/post/1/my-first-post.html'` = `/var/www/projects/current-project/public/cache/post/1/my-first-post.html` exists.

I don't want to set a `RewriteBase` because is dynamic for each develop environment.

How I can detect the cache file from current `.htaccess` folder?

**Working nginx version**:

```
set $cachefile "";

if ($uri ~ ^[a-z0-9/-]+$) {
    set $cachefile "/cache/$uri.html";
}

if ($uri = "/") {
    set $cachefile "/cache/index.html";
}

location / {
    try_files $cachefile $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

**WORKING SOLUTION** thanks to @Sumurai8:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # No request: index cache
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond $1#%{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^/?#(.*/public)/
    RewriteCond %1/cache/index.html -f
    RewriteRule ^$ cache/index.html [L,NC]

    # Request: page
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond $1#%{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^([a-z0-9/-]+)#(.*/public)/
    RewriteCond %2/cache/%1.html -f
    RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9/-]+)$ cache/$1.html [L,NC]

    # Catch all script and cache generator
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Thanks.

Comment: An alternative `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/$1.html -f

        RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9/-]+)$ cache/$1.html [L]`

Comment: @starkeen not valid, DOCUMENT_ROOT is not our web base path and in every environment is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-f` and other similar checks work on **filenames**, not urls. You should first match on `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}`, then construct your own filename.

```
RewriteCond $1#%{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^([a-z0-9/-]+)#(.*/public)/
RewriteCond %2/cache/%1.html -f
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9/-]+)$ cache/$1.html [L]
```

(`$1` is the first capture group of the rule, which contains the latter part of the cached file. In the second condition, `%2` is the second capture group of the previous condition, which contains the document root + current prefix.)

Alternatively, you can blindly rewrite to the cache, and rewrite again if the cache does not exist:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cache/
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9/-]+)$ cache/$1.html [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

In your case `index.php` would need to recognize the cache url, which might be troublesome.

Comment: Tested with:

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^(.*/public)/([a-z0-9/-]+)$
    RewriteCond %1/cache/%2.html -f
    RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9/-]+)$ cache/$1.html [L]

Log is:

    [Sun May 08 14:49:33.922789 2016] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 4206] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 127.0.0.1:44666] 127.0.0.1 - - [localhost/sid#7f2d26745ae0][rid#7f2d266820a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/public/] RewriteCond: input='/var/www/public/cache/post.html' pattern='-f' => not-matched, referer: http://localhost/public/

Comment: Hrmmmm... that variable is always a bit finecky. Let me try to change it around a bit.

Comment: Main problem in your solution is that REQUEST_URI is not from project path, is from DOCUMENT_ROOT and each develop has his own DOCUMENT_ROOT (http://localhost/projects/current-project/public/post/35/my-first-post or http://project.localhost/post/35/my-first-post or any else). Anyway, thanks for your comment.

Comment: Could you please test with removing the first condition and having `RewriteCond $1#{REQUEST_FILENAME} ...`? I am not entirely sure if the url as matched by the rule is available in the first condition. That might be a solution to your problem.

Comment: Perfect! do you have a small regular expression error: `[a-z0-9/0]` should be `[a-z0-9/-]`.

Comment: Was it the `$1` comment that made it work? Because in that case I'll update the answer with that too ;-)

Comment: Yes, was the `$1` I'm testing now rules for `index`, that aren't catched by current rules (uri is empty).